# How to get a channelId from an exchange item created for MSTeam team messages?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams

Messages in MSTeam appears in group/team mailbox in **Conversation History > Team Chat folder.** In case of a team/channel message,I didn't see an attribute to determine **channelID** a message item is associated with. The subject of the message item have channelname (for channel other than general) but channelname can change. So subject is not reliable to derive the channel info.

Is there any attribute to retrieve the channelId given a msteam message item in exchange.

Here is the MS TEAM named test1/hello for which message is being captured in the mentioned folder

[image: test1 team and channel hello]

[image: Entry in test1 mailobx]

Comment: These don't come from a "channel". Conversation History contains 1:1 and Team Meeting chat sessions, not threads from a channel.

Comment: Yes, it does. All the messages are stored in team/group mailbox  for group conversations in (Conversation Histroy>Team Chat) folder in case of team/channel chat. And it's inside individual mailbox in same folder for one to one messages.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur is correct. The items in that folder are not channel messages, which are stored in an entirely different system (the Skype Chat Service).

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Could you elaborate that please? Do you mean team messages are saved in two different systems then?  What is the purpose of the message in Conversation History>Team Chat folder? Only for  compliance?  https://www.petri.com/teams-compliance-story

Comment: @MarcLaFleur There is a hidden folder inside *Conversation History* named *Team Chat* where team/channel messages are saved. I am not referring to *Conversastion History* folder where Skype for Business messages are saved

Comment: Teams stores conversations in the Skype Chat Service. For chats (1:1 and meetings), it pushes a copy into Conversation History alongside Skype for Business. In part, this to reduce user confusion around Skype and Teams IM's, particularly since IMs can involve both systems. This is why there is no Channel ID, they were not created within the context of a Channel.

Comment: I am referring to team/channel messages and not 1:1 or skype for business. I have added the screen shots of how the messages appear in team mailbox so that we can be on same page.