# Reading recoverable items hidden folder using graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

When I use [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/mailFolders](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D/mailFolders) graph api, it only lists public folders. Is there a way to get all the hidden folders(Recoverable Items) in a mailbox like in EWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WellKnownFolderName enumerations should work okay eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@d.com')/MailFolders/RecoverableItemsRoot
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@d.com')/MailFolders/RecoverableItemsDeletion
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@d.com')/MailFolders/RecoverableItemsPurges
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@d.com')/MailFolders/RecoverableItemsVersions
```

otherwise look at Child Folders of the Root  eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders/Root/childfolders/?$Top=1000
```

Comment: Thanks @Glen . I worked it out using the root folder. But now I can't get the "Team Chat" Folder which resides in "Conversation History". https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/mailFolders/ConversationHistory?$expand=childFolders . It shows childFolderCount of 1 though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511756/how-to-get-a-channelid-from-an-exchange-item-created-for-msteam-team-messages

Comment: That folder is hidden so I'm pretty sure you can't get hidden folders with the Graph API. Actually you can't get non hidden folders that don't have a folder class (or subclass) or IPF.Note (using MailFolders). This is a bug IMO or maybe then need another endpoint for accessing everything etc . One thing however if you do a Search using the AllItems searchfolder it will show items from that TeamChat folder

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I was also thinking the same. Btw, I need to sync the folder items. So it won't help. Wondering if you can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511756/how-to-get-a-channelid-from-an-exchange-item-created-for-msteam-team-messages this?

Comment: I would suggest you look at the messages with a MAPI editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy this will give you all the properties that are available on a Message which EWSEditor won't show so maybe what your looking for is there in an extended property . Personally my experience is you don't see the Channel messages in the TeamChat folder just the IM's but I only have a limited number of active users. Hitting the Group Mailbox for the Team and accessing the Channel directly using Graph would probably be a better way.

Comment: It is there in groupmailbox Team Chat Folder. But pulling the messages from graph api for a team channel is not yet supported. Do you have the graph endpoint that works?

Comment: No that's where I stopped last time i looked it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168366/discussion-between-sameer-and-glen-scales).